# Custom tag implementation with tagify tags

Tags: javascript, frontend

It's my code here

```
tagifyInput = document.querySelector('input[name=tags]'),
        tagify = new Tagify(tagifyInput, {
            enforceWhitelist: true,
            whitelist: selected,
            template:{
                tag: function (v) {
                    return `<tag title='${v}' contenteditable='false' spellcheck="false">
                        <x title='remove tag' class='tagify__tag__removeBtn'></x>
                        <div>
                            <span class='tagify__tag-text'>${v}</span>
                        </div>
                    </tag>`;
                }
            }
        });
```

I am giving this template here also to tagify, but it's not working what could be the issue ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you can edit your post to have more answers. I suggest being more specific about what is not working and what you are trying to achieve by editing your post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: Does the browser's console shows an error?